# Union of a List of ConvexHullMesh

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, mesh

How can I create a Union of a List of several `ConvexHullMesh`?

My List is of variable length and the containing BoundaryMeshRegions may overlap. I want to create and visualize the Union of them and also calculate the totally covered area (avoiding to count overlapping regions twice or more).

**Edit:**
View of the individual `ConvexHullMesh`es:
[image: All my Hulls stacked]

`RegionUnion` fails:
[image: failing RegionUnion]

---

### 1 - Minimal failing Example

```
hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0}}];
hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5, 3, 1}];
hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5, 3, 2}];

hulls = Flatten[List[hulls0, hulls1, hulls2]];
RegionUnion @@ hulls
```

Ok, `hulls // Select[RegionDimension[#] == 2 &] // RegionUnion` helps.

---

### 2 - Minimal Failing Example (with small values)

```
hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0}}];
hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10*^-9, 10*^-9}, {5, 3, 1}];
hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10*^-9, 10*^-9}, {1000, 3, 2}];

hulls = Flatten[List[hulls0, hulls1, hulls2]];
hulls // Select[RegionDimension[#] == 2 &] // RegionUnion
```

Ok, scaling up the values helps

---

### 3 - Full failing Example

(Not being able to provide a minimal example that shows the same behaviour)

Try n=5. With `rmin` above a specific value, it works. At lower values it fails:

```
CirclePlus[x__] := Flatten[Union @@ Outer[Plus, x, 1], Length@{x} - 2];
mConfigs[rmin_, rmax_, nS_] := 
  Tuples[{{0, 0}, {rmin, rmax}}, nS];
rotateAbout[\[Alpha]_, pts_] := 
 RotationTransform[\[Alpha], {0, 0}][pts];
getLines[radiusList_, nS_] := 
Module[{baseLine},
 Table[
     rotateAbout[(i - 1)*2 \[Pi]/nS, {{0, 
     radiusList[[i]][[1]]}, {0, radiusList[[i]][[2]]}}]
  , {i, 1, nS}
  ]
 ]
getHull[lines_, color_] :=
Module[{mResult = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, i = 1},
 mResult = CirclePlus @@ lines;
 ConvexHullMesh[mResult, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {All -> Opacity[0.3, color]}]
 ]

Manipulate[
Show[

 res = Table[
     getHull[1*^9*24*^-6*getLines[mConfigs[rmin, 0.009, n][[i]], n], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][i/2^n]]
     , {i, 1, 2^n}
     ] // Select[RegionDimension[#] == 2 &] // RegionUnion

 , PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1
 ]

, {{rmin, 0.0075}, 0.000, 0.009}
, {{n, 5}, Table[2*i + 1, {i, 0, 6}]}
]
```

**Side-Problem:** For some reason, I cannot allow even numbers for n. When I do so, the `ConvexHullMesh` crashes again.

Comment: [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `RegionUnion` seems to fail with `BoundaryMeshRegion`s (see my EDIT)

Comment: Why do your hulls meshes have different colors?  The *basic* case seems to work:  `hulls = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5, 12, 2}];
RegionUnion[hulls]`  (It seems there is no need for `Apply` here but the output is the same either way.)

Comment: I just found out, that `RegionUnion` fails, as soon as there are Regions in my List, that are only Lines or Points. Is there a smart way to filter them out or handle them "intelligently"?

Comment: I suppose there should be but I can't think of one off hand.  I'll try to come back to this.

Comment: You could use `RegionDimension` to filter them out.  If you still have problems, please post a simple example that we can just copy and play with and try to fix.

Comment: @Szabolcs Failing example added. Using `RegionDimension`, I get a useful List of the dimension of each Region, but I seem to lack some syntax-skills to get only those Regions of my initial List whose dimension is 2.

Comment: @DPF - I can't get the third example to fail, no matter how small I make `rmin`.  It only fails when the `rmin` slider moves all the way to the right for the largest values.  In that case, the polygons are so small that there is no region to take the union of.

Comment: @JasonB very interesting. When I just copy and paste the third example to a fresh .nb, it fails for example at `rmin=0.00228`  (Mathematica 10.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employing Szabolcs's recommendation to use [`RegionDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDimension.html) to solve your Minimal failing Example:

```
Pick[hulls, RegionDimension /@ hulls, 2] // RegionUnion
```

[image]

Equivalently:

```
hulls // Select[RegionDimension[#] == 2 &] // RegionUnion
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Even though i (again) have to scale my values up, as in [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120604/convexhullmesh-fails-with-small-numbers)

Comment: @DPF Uh oh, found a problem?  (I do intend to return to the earlier issue by the way.)

Comment: Yes, see my other example above

Comment: @DPF Yeah, that's not good.  I guess that problem runs pretty deep.

Comment: Please see my third example above. Scaling up helps in various but not all cases.

Comment: @DPF I tried to figure out what is going on here but I didn't get very far.  Perhaps if I spent several continuous hours on it I might learn something important, or not, but frankly I feel that I shouldn't have to.  I hope you report (all) these problems to Wolfram Research, and I hope you will share their reply, assuming that does not break confidentiality.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I think I'm going to ask another question with the full example...

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, even though there are cases where it doesnt work - but that may be because of my application specific issues

Answer (score 3):

Another method that seems to work as well on the first example is to extract the polygons from the mesh regions, and then create a region from them:

```
MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ hulls // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Works for example 1, but crashes in example 3, when `n > 3`

Comment: I get it to work with `n=5` and `rmin = 0.0075`  http://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLiM.png

Comment: Ok, me too, but again not for smaller `rmin`